# Reorder line buttons in Backpack laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have created a custom button `status_history` and i placed it at end of the stack `$this->crud->addButtonFromView('line', 'History', 'status_history', 'end');` and now i want to place it before the `edit` button? How can i do that ?

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far, your question lacks clarity?

Comment: I've placed it at the end of the stack and now i want to change the order `$this->crud->addButtonFromView('line', 'History', 'status_history', 'end');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the fluent syntax](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fluent-syntax#fluent-buttons) is the shortest way to do that, you can do:

```php
CRUD::button('status_history')->after('update')->view('status_history');
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the array syntax, you can call one of these after your `addButtonFromView` call:

- `$this->crud->moveButton($target, $where, $destination)` - see [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Buttons.php#L175-L209)
- `$this->crud->orderButtons(string $stack, array $order)` - see [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Buttons.php#L22-L58)

Looks like these methods are not properly documented (or at all) - sorry for that, will fix ASAP. Until then, the docblocks should explain what they do very well.